# Xtext Validation

Tags: validation, xtext, string-function

I currently have project where i had to make my own DSL. I have my DSL and also the most of my Validation. I got stucked by the fact that i wanted to check if a specific word contains a number.

I wrote a grammar, which allows you to create the following code:

```
Category Doors belongs to Group Car_Equiptment;
Category Engine belongs to Group Car_Equiptment;

 Doors properties: 
   -5_Doors
   -4_Doors

 Engine properties:
   -V8 180 "PS" 
   -V10 200 "PS"
```

Here the grammer definition:

```
   Category:
    'Category' name=ID 'belongs' 'to' (group+=Group) ';' 
;

PropHeader:
    name=[Category]  'properties' ':'
    (properties+=Properties)+
;

Properties:
    '-'  name=ID number=INT? description=STRING? 
;
```

I should controll that the user doesn't choose a door property, which is over 5 Doors. I can get the properties name with out a problem but i'm missing a funtion which si helping me to check if the string contains a number. Since i have a lot of different properties i can't just make a ID only for the Doors. I have to check via Validaiotn if a property named doors is exsisting (i have this part already) and if yes is any of the string contains a number higher then 5.

Comment: this is more of a java question isnt it? not xtext related? did you consider using regular expressions? or a split and a test for a number foreach splitted part?

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I read somthing that the validation code should be like JUnit4 but it wasn't working with that code. With Java  it's working now. Thanks a lot. I could have come to that idea on my own to use regular java.